Issues with Aliyun Scheduler extender in AKS
I am trying to use Aliyun scheduler extender to be able to use a T4 nVidia GPU with multiple PODs, I have a managed AKS cluster with a default NodePool with standard VMs (Standard_D2_v3) and added an User NodePool with Standard_NC4as_T4_v3 instances, all running Ubuntu 22.04.4, I enabled default nVidia driver installation and have the driver and nvidia-smi running
I am following instructions given here to install the Aliyun even though I'm using right now version 1.24.4 of the Kube-Scheduler, the DaemonSet (gpushare-device-plugin) and SchedulerExtender (gpushare-schd-extender) versions remains the same, also, I've provided a working KubeConfig for the scheduler in /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf path that is mounted by the KubeScheduler POD and has access to the K8S API. My Kubernetes version is 1.28 running on AKS with.
My issue is: after verifying that the custom KubeScheduler actually works on the GPU nodes and the Aliyun DaemonSet and gpushare-schd-extender PODs are up and running, when I create a POD requesting aliyun.com/gpu-mem resources the POD fails with the message:
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli.real: device error: no-gpu-has-4MiB-to-run: unknown device: unknown

Taking a look at various logs I get the following:
SchedulerExtenderLogs (repeated many times):
[ debug ] 2024/06/02 21:15:12 controller.go:295: No need to update pod name my-pod-7df6444f8c-wfd9f in ns my-namespace and old status is Running, new status is Running; its old annotation map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container:my-service] and new annotation map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container:my-service]
[ debug ] 2024/06/02 21:15:42 controller.go:295: No need to update pod name my-pod-7df6444f8c-wfd9f in ns my-namespace and old status is Running, new status is Running; its old annotation map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container:my-service] and new annotation map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container:my-service]

Device Plugin DS logs:
I0602 21:02:24.218109       1 server.go:222] Starting to serve on /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/aliyungpushare.sock
I0602 21:02:24.224822       1 server.go:230] Registered device plugin with Kubelet
I0602 21:03:40.053214       1 allocate.go:46] ----Allocating GPU for gpu mem is started----
I0602 21:03:40.053233       1 allocate.go:57] RequestPodGPUs: 4
I0602 21:03:40.053239       1 allocate.go:61] checking...
I0602 21:03:40.079992       1 podmanager.go:112] all pod list [{{ }

.... (BUNCH OF INFO FROM POD MANIFEST)


I0602 21:03:40.080378       1 podmanager.go:123] list pod my-pod-7df6444f8c-wfd9f in ns my-namespace in node aks-gpu2pt27-29617350-vmss00000d and status is Pending
I0602 21:03:40.080387       1 podutils.go:81] No assume timestamp for pod my-pod-7df6444f8c-wfd9f in namespace my-namespace, so it's not GPUSharedAssumed assumed pod.
W0602 21:03:40.080395       1 allocate.go:152] invalid allocation request: request GPU memory 4 can't be satisfied.

I have verified that the NodePort service of the SchedulerExtender is open on the 32766 port, also tried setting the urlPrefix of the KubeScheduler configuration to the DNS of the AKS Master Node with no luck.
I left an issue open on the Aliyun Github repo, however, if someone may have an advice that will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

If someone faces this same issue, I wrote an article explaining how I resolved the issue and 2 approaches to get the Aliyun Scheduler Extender to work.
https://medium.com/@diego.satizabal_81239/using-aliyun-gpu-share-in-an-azure-aks-717cf7392d05
